# How can you scale stairs to decrease per step?

Tags: modeling

[image: gate]

Hello, i am buliding some kind of gate or portal. I used the Array Modifier on a block to get stairs and wondered if there is a way to make it decrease per every step. I want the stairs to get smaller to the top.

Comment: Make *what* decrease every step?

Comment: Maybe i am using the wrong term here. I want the stairs to get smaller to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it using the ***proportional editing (Linear falloff)***.
[image]

Apply the *Array Modifier*, then select the face of the very top stair and snap the cursor (with the *3D Cursor pivot type* enabled) to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*). Enable the ***proportional editing*** with ***Linear falloff*** type, press <kbd>S</kbd>, then set its range using <kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd>. Scale the mesh to the desired size.

**NOTE:** You may add a ***shape key*** before scaling to make the transformation work non destructively.
[image]

Comment: when you write face, do you mean just the plane on the backside of the highest step as it appears in the GIF?

Comment: YUP. As in .GIF :).

Comment: i finally did it. it´s important to use the y-axis while scaling by simply pressing y. When you don´t do that and don´t use a shape key (also important to press that button and adjust Key 1 to 1 as in the GIF) as in your NOTE it bulges a little, what´s also kinda unproportional. Your way is a little more accurate than using SimpleDeform because the stairs stay horizontal at the sides. By using SimpleDeform the stairs tilt a little to the inside (don´t know if that´s teh proper way to describe it).

Answer (score 3):

Add a "Simple Deform" modifier. Then select "Taper" and check either "Lock Y Axis" or "Lock X Axis" . Then adjust the "Deform Factor"

[image: Simple Deform]

Comment: That´s exactly what i was looking for. Did you make that GIF?

Comment: Yes, I made the GIF :)